# Center programmatically created UIView in self.view, both iPhone 3.5 & 4 inch?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I created a UIView programmatically in `viewDidLoad` and simply want to center it in `self.view`. With the iPhone 5, the view is correctly centered. When I switch to the 3.5 simulator my view is pushed towards the bottom of `self.view`.

What in the world could I be doing wrong? My xib has nothing but a empty view inside, and even if I create my view not specifying a xib I get the same result.

How do I simply center my new UIView in `self.view` without jumping through a million hoops?

EDIT:

My code is as simple as it gets:

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width)];
newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
newView.center = self.view.center;
```

I'm not sure why my question is being downvoted as it's pretty straightforward what I'm trying to do. If there's something missing please let me know so I can adjust my question accordingly.

Comment: Post the code you use to create the view.

Comment: probably the autoresize mask has not been set properly for your view.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to tell us if your app is using auto layout or struts and springs. The answer is completely different depending on which you're using.

If you're using auto layout then the center position is pretty much ignored and what matters is the constraints you put on the view.

If you're not using auto layout, the code above isn't right. The center property of view is in the coordinate system of the superview.

Your code to set the center should look like this:

```
CGPoint center = [self.view convertPoint self.view.center fromView: self.view.superview];
newView.center = center;
```

But as I say, if you're using auto layout then that won't make any difference.

Comment: Is autolayout an app-wide setting? I was under the impressions it was set for each viewController independently. If I load my viewController with just `alloc init` (no nib) then is autolayout enabled? I tried your code and I get the same result, so I assume autolayout is enabled? How would I disable it then?

Comment: autolayout is controlled for an interface file (Storyboard or XIB file). I don't know what determines it if you use loadView and create your UI in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use autosizing with this code

```
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] init];
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

This will give
   [image]

So the view will stay where you add it and will not change while the size of the device changes.